# Python Module Package with no methods

Tags: python, module

I wrote a Python module which is just two methods, help and check.  Check just takes a string file name and does something with it.  When I import the module, there are no methods in it.  Only `__name__` and the like, but neither check nor help appears in the dir.

I am just importing the file.  lyricCheck.py

Here's my code in lyricCheck.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#python lyric checker
#Jim Boulter
#January 19, 2015
#Copyright 2015

import sys
import urllib2
import fileinput
from decimal import *
from re import *
from pygoogle import pygoogle

def help():
    print 'usage: python check.py filename.txt\n'
    print 'input line structure: artist name; song title\n'

def check(filename):
    if(str(filename).lower == "help" or str(filename).lower == "-h"):
        help()
        return
    #do lots of other stuff
```

Comment: did you import by doing `import lyricCheck`?  if so, did you try `dir(lyricCheck)`?

Comment: How are you importing it, and how are you trying to access the methods? Unrelated: You forgot to call the `lower` function: `str(filename).lower()`.

Comment: I import with import lyricCheck and when I use dir(lyricCheck) I get this:

`['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

Comment: `from lyricCheck import help, check`

Comment: where are the files? in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, same folder.  When I do `from lyricCheck import help, check` I get `ImportError: cannot import name help`

Comment: Do I correctly recreate your issue in my answer?

Comment: on a side note `help` is a builtin function so might not be the best name for a function

Comment: Good point, use a module level docstring, i.e.`'''this module does x'''` at the top of the module, and you can get that help with help(module) when it is imported. If you put it in your `__init__.py` with your functions, it will live nicely together. You might also check out the `optparse` or `argparse` module for using it as a script with command line parameters and command line help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating your package like this, and I believe you are, you need to import your module from your package:

```
~/tmp$ mkdir lyricCheck
~/tmp$ cd lyricCheck/
~/tmp/lyricCheck$ touch __init__.py
~/tmp/lyricCheck$ cat > lyricCheck.py
#!/usr/bin/python
#python lyric checker
#Jim Boulter
#January 19, 2015
#Copyright 2015

import sys
import urllib2
import fileinput
from decimal import *
from re import *
from pygoogle import pygoogle

def help():
    print 'usage: python check.py filename.txt\n'
    print 'input line structure: artist name; song title\n'

def check(filename):
    if(str(filename).lower == "help" or str(filename).lower == "-h"):
        help()
        return
    #do lots of other stuff
~/tmp/lyricCheck$ cd ..
~/tmp$ python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lyricCheck
>>> dir(lyricCheck)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

Here's my payoff, and this should have worked if I had pygoogle, so this is how I know I found the issue:

```
>>> from lyricCheck import lyricCheck
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lyricCheck/lyricCheck.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pygoogle import pygoogle
ImportError: No module named pygoogle
```

You can put this in your `__init__.py` file to import the functions from the lower level module and make them available right at the package level:

```
from lyricCheck import help, check
```

---

Also note, when you do this:

```
from decimal import *
from re import *
```

You dump all the names in those modules into your module's namespace. It's generally considered better to declare them individually.

Comment: That was my next issue.  You're a mind reader.  Take the rest of the night off.

Comment: @jboulter11 Glad to help, but please don't go off upvoting all my material, though, after so much, SO will think I'm running your account. But feel free to look over my material here, it's quite good, or so I think, and if you think the material is worthy in the context, give it a nudge upwards. :)